# I have installed Format Factory using PlayOnLinux, but the shortcut I created is not working!

Tags: wine, icons, playonlinux

I have installed Format Factory using PlayOnLinux, but the shortcut I created is not working! Here the .desktop file with r&w permissions at both ends.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Format Factory
Exec=/home/shivu/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/VirtualDrive/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/FormatFactory/FormatFactory.exe
Icon=/home/shivu/Pictures/Icons/Format Factory Icon.jpeg
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
Path=/home/shivu/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/VirtualDrive/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/FormatFactory/
Comment=Format Factory
GenericName=Format Factory
```

Comment: In general, spaces and characters like `'`, `(`, `)` and some others should be appropriately escaped. See https://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201607/page03.html. I don't know if this applies to lines in .desktop files for Wine applications.

Comment: I simply reinstalled PlayOnLinux and the shortcut worked! I don't know how PlayOnLinux was corrupted or removed by some app!